# How to send requests via virtual interface

Tags: linux, networking

I have created a virtual interface using

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.50.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Now I'm sending a request to a server via the virtual interface using curl:

```
curl --interface 192.168.50.10 http://192.168.50.1:8080/myhostedapp
```

This works fine and my app shows the source ip as 192.168.50.10, but if the server is on a different subnet, and reachable from the physical interface (eth0), the connection times out.

So this works (via the physical interface):
`curl http://10.10.50.1:8080/myhostedapp`.

But this fails:
`curl --interface 192.168.50.10 http://10.10.50.1:8080/myhostedapp`.

For `10.10.50.1` to reach `192.168.50.10`, I added it to the route table.

What do I need to configure so that `10.10.50.1` is reachable from `192.168.50.10`?

Comment: Your two IPs 10.10.50.1 and 192.168.60.10 are in different subnets, so you will need a router in between. But that is off-topic for SO...

Comment: The server 10.10.50.1 is accessible from my local machine via the real ip. The issue is that it cannot be reached via virtual IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set iptunnel you can see this link it would make it more clear, one more thing when you added route you added the route with a gateway.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/linux-networking-routing-to-virtual-ip-addresses-from-a-different-subnet

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using the iptunnel and let you know how it goes.
And yes, I added route on the server 10.10.50.1 with gateway as the IP of my local machine. I'm able to ping from server to local machine.

Comment: sure pls try iptunnel would be waiting for the update

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't use `ifconfig` anymore. It is unmaintained since 10 years or so and known to have some issues, esp. regarding "virtual interfaces".

Better use `ip` from the `iproute2` package.

See also this articles about `ifconfig` vs. `ip` and what the replacement commands look like:

- [Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/)
- [iproute2: Life after ifconfig](http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/02/24/iproute2-life-after-ifconfig/)
- [ifconfig sucks](http://inai.de/2008/02/19)

Now regarding your issue: what does your routing table look like? Please provide the output of `ip address show eth0` and `ip route show`. I suspect your routing table to be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the info on iproute2. I'll retry after setting it up with ip.